# Vector space in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

Do the set of all square-integrable normalized functions necessarily form a vector space in quantum mechanics? The reason for this question being my problem in not understanding why the zero is not included in the vector space.

Comment: Why do you think the zero vector is not included?

Answer (score 6):

1. The set ${\cal L}^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ of [square integrable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-[vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), and hence includes $0$.
2. The set $\{\psi\in{\cal L}^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\mid ||\psi ||=1\}$ of normalized wavefunctions is *not* a vector space, e.g. because the set is not stable against multiplication with a constant.
3. The set $\{\psi\in{\cal L}^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\mid 0<||\psi || <\infty\}$ of normalizable wavefunctions is *not* a vector space, e.g. because it does not include 0.